# Function is changing matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Just a warning that this is a college assignment, and therefore I am not allowed to use python functions other than `len()`. I don't mind if anyone wants to answer with functions or not, just know that's why my code looks terrible.

The assignment is for me to create a 10x10 matrix and with multiple functions add elements to it depending on the x or y position, checking if the space is available or not. The original instruction is to create a 10x10 with '.' instead of zeroes, so that it would look better in the terminal. I decided to keep using 0 and only change to '.' in the printing process. I print the matrix every time I make a change. I use this function:

```
def printMatrixF(M):
    fM = M
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            if fM[i][j] == 0:
                fM[i][j] = '.'
            print(fM[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
```

But this function is somehow changing the `M` value, even though I'm pretty sure it shouldn't.
Here is a smaller portion of the code that shows my exact problem:

```
def createMatrix():
    a = [0]*10
    for i in range(10):
        a[i] = [0]*10
    return a

def printMatrix(M):
    for i in range(len(M)):
        print(M[i])

def printMatrixF(M):
    fM = M
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            if fM[i][j] == 0:
                fM[i][j] = '.'
            print(fM[i][j],end=" ")
        print()

M = createMatrix()
printMatrix(M)
printMatrixF(M)
printMatrix(M)
```

The `printMatrix()` function only prints the matrix, and the `printMatrixF()` has the added change from 0 to '.' in it. This feels so dumb but I have no idea what's causing this.

(Edit: I'm using the same function but using `if` to revert back the '.'s to 0s (and it works I guess).

Comment: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-functions-modify-lists-dictionaries-python/

Comment: `fM = M` doesn't make a copy of anything; you now just have a second name that refers to the matrix.  There's no need to modify anything while printing, anyway: set a local variable to the element of matrix, then print either that or a dot.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Oof, I'm toast. Can't use .copy()

Comment: @jasonharper so I make a local variable for all the elements and print them? Would that just cause the same problem

Comment: No, for each individual element as you loop through the matrix.  `x = fM[i][j]` / `if x==0: print('.')` / `else: print(x)` for example.

Comment: Instead of changing a value in `M` or `fM` or anything else, just use conditional logic on the original value *to decide what to `print`*.

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3 and a statement in Python 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fM = M` only assigns another name to object `M` refers to — so you need to make a copy of it. This could be done using the `copy` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy), but since you can't use that, you can do it manually by making use of the `copy()` [*method*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) that all `list` objects have.

In the code below I've created a `copyMatrix(M)` function to illustrate how to use it:

```
def createMatrix():
    a = [0]*10
    for i in range(10):
        a[i] = [0]*10
    return a

def printMatrix(M):
    for i in range(len(M)):
        print(M[i])

def copyMatrix(M):
    """Return a copy of matrix M."""
    mcopy = []
    for i in range(len(M)):
        # Append copy of sublist.
        mcopy.append(M[i].copy())  # Could also use M[i][:]
    return mcopy

def printMatrixF(M):
    fM = copyMatrix(M)
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            if fM[i][j] == 0:
                fM[i][j] = '.'
            print(fM[i][j],end=" ")
        print()

M = createMatrix()
printMatrix(M)
print()
printMatrixF(M)
print()
printMatrix(M)
```